# How do i duplicate a js click counter on my html page

Tags: javascript, function

I have a javascript click counter on my html page for a my first blog post. Now i want to duplicate the js click counters for all other ten posts on the page, So every blog post has its own independent click counter. How do i do that?

Comment: Can you show us your existing code so we can offer advice on that?

Comment: please provide enough information to make it possible to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

According to the information you give, the best method to resolve your problem and duplicate JavaScript code is probably the following.

> CTRL+C CTRL+V